# Android Studio's emulator alternative

Tags: android

I have searched Android emulators on google but I'm confused which should I download and use..Android studios emulator has more size than other emulators any idea as I'm beginner to android,which emulator will be best.Thanks

Comment: Opinion questions like this are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/),but Android Studio's emultaors are better choice.